# How do I setup a shortcut for "change default download folder"?

Tags: macos, google-chrome, keyboard-shortcuts, browser, download

In OS X, I want to setup a keyboard shortcut to change my default Google Chrome download location instead of digging through the settings every time.

How can I do this?

Answer (score -1):

If you are using IDM then check the box as below picture

[Picture Link for IDM](http://img809.imageshack.us/img809/4718/xgac.png)

If you are using others then select the whole path and copy it whereas next time you can use it

Comment: The OP does not use IDM. Also, how would copying the path work? From where? To where? The OP needs a keyboard shortcut.

Comment: OP can use http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/14249/create-custom-windows-key-keyboard-shortcuts-in-windows/  or broser download folder setting like for chrome http://img823.imageshack.us/img823/4909/qq1z.png

Comment: The OP is on OS X, not Windows.